# Mixing isometric illustration and real-life pictures. Do or don't?

Tags: branding, isometric

So I'm building a brand using isometric illustration.
But I was starting to think if it would be possible, aesthetically speaking, to combine isometric illustration with pictures...
Have you seen that before? Any example would be great.
Or if you wouldn't recommend... Why?

Comment: I think you must try it and share it to receive comments. An image worths more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen many images where someone had opened a box and looks out gladly surprised. The box and the outcoming content can well be isometric projections, because it shows the box & contents well. It can work even when the box and the shiny content are drawn and the image of the opener is a photo.